# Form groups of items, without repetition, that fit a defined value

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm having a hard time finding a solution for a spreadsheet on google sheets, javascript language. I was seeing some things like group by and discard. But I still haven't been able to assemble anything mentally that would come to any result.

I need to find items and groups of items (summed) within a dataset that fits the given defined value.

I have a data sheet with defined values, here is an example list

| item | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100.00 |
| 2 | 53.50 |
| 3 | 45.00 |
| 4 | 67.00 |
| 5 | 32.50 |
| 6 | 35.60 |
| 7 | 34.70 |

I need groups of items to be formed so that their sum is ideally 100.00, but it can be something close to that, even a little higher would be possible, but the ideal would be up to (<=).

Expected result logic:

- Group 1 = item 1 value 100.00
- Group 2 = item 4 value 67.00 and item 5 value 32.50 (since the sum is
  99.50, being the closest to 100)
- Group 3 = item 2 value 53.50 and item 3 value 45.00 (since the sum is 98.50, being the closest to 100)
- Group 4 = item 6 value 35.60 + item 7 value 34.70 (since the sum is 70.30)

It doesn't matter the order of the items or the formation of the item groups. Only items cannot be repeated.

As an output you would only need the items from each group. Ex:

```
1

4 5

2 3

6 7
```

But if it had all the results it would be excellent (group, items, total value)

```
Group 1 item(s) 1 total value 100.00

Group 2 item(s) 4 5 total value 99.50

Group 3 item(s) 2 3 total value 98.50

Group 4 item(s) 6 7 total value 70.30
```

I'm thinking this way, but I still haven't found how to do it

| Action | Rule | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Check the maximum value of an ITEM as the LIMITER cannot be lower | Maximum value | Show maximum value. Ex: 100 |
| Set LIMITER as long as it is equal to or less than an ITEM's maximum value | <=MaximumValue | Example: LIMITER: 100 |
| Check if any ITEM has a value equal to the LIMITER 100 | value == LIMIT | Set in sequential order (+1 in each cycle) the group number for items with a value of 100 first |
| check if any sum of ITEM is equal to LIMITER 100 | sum of items = value of the limiter, without repeating items already listed | Set in sequential order (+1 in each cycle) the number of the group of items summed with a value of 100 |
| check if any ITEM is = -0.01 which previous search | without repeating items already listed | Set in sequential order (+1 in each cycle) the number of the group of items with values lower than the limiter |
| check if any sum of items is = -0.01 which previous search | sum of items = value of fetched, without repeating items already listed | Set in sequential order (+1 in each cycle) the group number for summed items with values lower than the limiter |
| continue searches until no values remain | without repeating items already listed | Set list to last available item |

Every help is welcome

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this question is very similar to the knapsack problem. I'm not very good at explaining it, but here are some resources that do a far better job of explaining it than I could.

https://learnersbucket.com/examples/algorithms/knapsack-problem-in-javascript/